# Bad lag when playing League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

I have had LoL for around 6 months, and for about 1 month my ping has been crazy and I have been having a problem where whenever I try to move my champ, or use an ability or spell or anything, it has a 2-3 second delay, making it hard for me to play the game.

I am using a Macbook Air, which is connected to my Wifi. It is not a problem with my computer because when I bring it to my friends houses, it works fine and my ping is always under 300.

My Ping reached 20 000 recently and that is a little worrying :/
I would really appreciate an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Either your pc setup for your internet went wrong somehow, or your internet is failing. You should get help from the ISP, to check the modem, etc.

Comment: Do you play any other online games? How's your connection in them?

Comment: Have you gone over your download limit and thus your ISP is rate limiting your connection?

Comment: Someone got access to your wifi and uses all the bandwidth on it. If you can try being connected with a cable instead and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It would help to mention your internet provider. Also Riot themselves have been having lag issues

Comment: Are there any other people in your household using your internet connection? If someone is using Netflix, for instance, that might or might not cause your ping to skyrocket, depending on what networking hardware you're using (such as wireless access point, router or DSL modem).

Answer (score 1):

Riot has been having issues as of late with Verizon FiOS. If you're on the East Coast and have Verizon FiOS, this is more than likely the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ISP, and region, your packets might take a sub-optimal path. One way to work around is to use a Gaming VPN, which is basically a VPN but slightly optimized for games.

While I haven't personally used it, wtfast.com seems reasonably good at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your computer hardware and system software can RUN League of Legends (LoL)

Check [League of Legends FPS Lag Fix](http://dexteroid.com/how-to/league-of-legends-fps-lag-crash-sound-login-issues/) to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible issues at play here.

Router/Wifi doesn't have strong signal, or is suffering from heavy usage.  Might want to check your routers logs and see who connects to it.

If your router has usage statistics, showing bandwidth and who uses it, I would check that.

The obvious, check and make sure torrents aren't going on your network, can't tell you how many games I've played where, "WTF GODDAMNIT LAG!!!" Is followed by Steam updates, OS updates or torrent usage in background or on other systems in their network.

Otherwise, once you have checked all that, pick up WinMTR it basically automates what is called a tracert which measures latency between routing nodes to the end-point.  Basically tells you where the connection is broken.

Aside from that, it might be router settings.  My friends PC has a wireless card that even sitting 5ft from the router he disconnects from LAN based games.  I have the same PC with a different wireless card sitting a foot further and never have any problems.(inb4 MacBook Air)

Answer (score -1):

First, clean off your router/Box of Internet Glory and make sure dust hasn't settled anywhere near sensitive parts. Dust causes a LOT of overheating, and should be avoided. Next, use WTFast, and connect to the server closest to you, selecting manual setup and clicking auto select on whichever closest city. And last, don't put your Box of Internet Glory next to your TV/microwave, as these signals may affect your connection. Happy trolling!

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at your Router's Firewall Settings?  Gaming is notorious for getting picked up by Firewalls.  Here is a forum post recommending ports to open on your router:

https://www.astaro.org/gateway-products/network-protection-firewall-nat-qos-ips/50702-port-forwarding-league-legends.html

> 5000 - 5500 UDP - League of Legends Game Client
>
> 8393 - 8400 TCP - Patcher and Maestro
>
> 2099 TCP - PVP.Net
>
> 5223 TCP - PVP.Net
>
> 5222 TCP - PVP.Net
>
> 80 TCP - HTTP Connections
>
> 443 TCP - HTTPS Connections
>
> 8088 Spectator Mode

This may improve your connection significantly.  There is additional testing you can do on your connection to improve performance with gaming.

Wifi may not be an issue, but to rule this out as a possible cause, you should plug your computer into the ethernet and see if there are any performance changes when you are hard-wired in.

As to whether this idea has any merit, there perhaps some background understanding of how a port, networking, and firewall work is needed:

https://serverfault.com/questions/208522/what-is-strict-moderate-and-open-nat

Comment: Port forwarding would not resolve lag.  It resolves *connection* issues.

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  Firewalls can cause packet loss which can cause lag

Comment: That's an all or nothing thing.  Either the firewall is configured properly, and lets all the packets through, or it doesn't, and none get through.  If it's causing packet loss, that's not a port forwarding issue.

Comment: Do you have any links to prove that?  If a port is blocked, the application may default to use another port.  If it goes through this cycle multiple times, then it may cause the server to send data to a port, see that the data failed, and use the backup port.  How are you so sure it's not a port issue other than your expert intuition?  I've experienced the slowdowns on XBOX Live when the ports are not open for ALL of the services.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a piece of software cycling through multiple ports, in the event one is blocked.  If anything, it picks one (for the session, or forever), and that's what you use.  Sometimes, that's configurable.  Sometimes it's not.  I work with software on a daily basis, and that includes firewalls; while your theory has some merit, it doesn't pan out in practice.

Comment: @Frank I really wish you could provide some supporting documentation for your assertions.  I'm a software developer so I understand firewalls and firewall issues very well.  It could be a result of dynamic port allocation, where the server selects a random port in a range.  If that port is blocked, I believe it will cause connection issues to the extent that OP is describing

Comment: Yes.  A *connection* issue.  Not a lag issue.  When the game starts, it will typically choose a port, and that's where you'll either get a successful connection, or not.  Not lag.  They are two very different things.  I'm also a software developer, with a bit of dabbling into hardware and other things.  I'm unsure of why supporting documentation for standard network protocols are required, but your assertion of software cycling ports does not.  I'm describing basic functionality, so I'm not even sure *why* I need to prove that.